# Is it possible to check if relation was included in Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have model with lot of relations through one specific relation. Is it possible to check if that relation was included in builder somewhere before?

For example:

```
$users->when($request->get('some-thing'), function($query, $id) {
    $query->whereHas('entries.some_thing', function($_query) {
    });
})->when($request->get('other-thing'), function($query, $id) {
    $query->whereHas('entries.other_thing', function($_query) {
    });
})->when($request->get('third-thing'), function($query, $id) {
    $query->whereHas('entries.third_thing', function($_query) {
    });
});

// .......

if ($users->entries_was_not_included()) {
    $users->has('entries')
}

$users = $users->get();
```

The idea is that to skip extra include of it already joined somewhere else.

Comment: There is no elegant way to achieve this. You would have to check all the entries in `$users->getQuery()->wheres`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible

```
if ($user->relationLoaded('entries')) {
    // entries are loaded code
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_relationLoaded).

Comment: it's not model. It's `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`

Comment: So doesn't work this way? Show relevant code of interaction with DB.

Comment: I followed what has written out there: "I have model with lot of relations through one specific relation. Is it possible to check if that relation was included in builder somewhere before?". You can set (if applicable for you there) `$with` protected array property in `User` model and declare there which relation you want to get always. So, for example `$with = ['addresses', 'grades']` `$user = \App\User::find(1);` will get you that user with eagerly loaded addresses and grades. This is bit expensive since it is eagerly loaded so watch out what kind of queries you have there for using this.

Comment: Updated example

Comment: What happens if `relationLoaded('relationName')` method is used? You can also check [`loadMissing()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_loadMissing) method.

Comment: Nothing. It's `QueryBuilder`, not actual model. `relationLoaded` is for loaded model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191149/discussion-between-tpojka-and-user1692333).